# Could somebody please help me with this code?

Tags: python

Could somebody please help me?  I have written this python code but for some reason it does not correctly respond to my if and elif statements.

```
print ('Welkom')
print("\n")

naam = input('Typ alsjeblieft je naam en druk vervolgens op enter: ')
print("\n")

if naam == 'Tim' or 'tim':
    print ('Hoi Tim')
elif naam == 'Mitch' or 'mitch':
    print ('Hoi Mitch')
elif naam == 'Tom' or 'tom':
    print ('Hoi Tom')
else:
    print ('Hoi vreemdeling!')
```

It does not matter what i input (like mitch) it will always print 'Hoi Tim'. I tried the same code with numbers and expressions like input == 20. In those cases it does respond to my if statements. Could somebody explain to me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`if naam == 'Tim' or 'tim'` is interpreted as:

```
if (naam == 'Tim') or ('tim')
```

Which will always be `True`, because `bool('tim') is True` (a string that isn't empty is considered True). And so, you have something like `False or True`, which will return `True` (because one of the values is True).

If you wanted to compare the input to two strings, you have to do something like:

```
if naam == 'Tim' or naam ==  'tim':
```

Or:

```
if name in ('Tim', 'tim'):
```

However, for your example, you can use [`str.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower):

```
if naam.lower() == 'tim':
```

This is the same for your other ones:

```
elif naam.lower() == 'mitch':
    print('Hoi Mitch')
elif naam.lower() == 'tom':
    print('Hoi Tom')
```

Comment: Also, I think `input` includes the `\n` at the end of the string. They will have to call `.rstrip()`

Comment: `input()` doesn't include the newline.

Comment: Thank you for your response Haidro. Your explanation is very clear. I do have a question. Which of the methods would you advise and why?

Comment: @user2756101 Oops, didnt see this comment until now. I prefer using `.lower` simply because it's shorter and more readable. As for performance, then doing `if name in ('Tim', 'tim')` may be the fastest

Answer (score 1):

If the values to be compared increase, you can do something like this

```
if naam in ('Tim', 'tim'):
    print ('Hoi Tim')
elif naam in ('Mitch', 'mitch'):
    print ('Hoi Mitch')
elif naam in ('Tom', 'tom'):
    print ('Hoi Tom')
else:
    print ('Hoi vreemdeling!')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How should interpret in? Is it something like elif naam in(includes)? 

And can I write as many option as I would like to when using in?

Comment: When you use `in` you can list all the options in a tuple or in a python list. If any of the items match, it will return true.